# Image of any curve can be parametrized without zero derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves, curves

Let $\gamma :[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be a $C^{1} ([a,b])$ injective application. Prove that there is another continuous parametrization $\rho:[c,d]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the following two sets are equal:

$\gamma([a,b])=\rho([c,d])$,

and $\rho$ admits lateral derivatives at each point on $[c,d]$ with the property that $\rho'_+ (t)\neq (0,0), \ \rho'_{-}(t)\neq (0,0),\ \forall\ t\in [c,d]$.

P.S. I have use the following notations: $\rho'_{+}(t_0)=\lim\limits_{t\searrow t_0}\dfrac{\rho(t)-\rho(t_0)}{t-t_0}$ and $\rho'_{-}(t_0)=\lim\limits_{t\nearrow t_0}\dfrac{\rho(t)-\rho(t_0)}{t-t_0}$.

Comment: I don't think this is true without additional assumptions. Take $\gamma(t) = p$ ( a constant curve). How are you going to reparametrize this with nonzero left and right derivatives? You have no means to leave the point $p$.

Comment: I have edited my post. Sorry...

Answer (score 4):

It's not true (even if you disregard constant functions).  It is possible to define a $C^\infty$ function $\gamma$ from $[0,1]$ into $\mathbb R^2$ such that $\gamma(t) = [0,0]$ for infinitely many $t$ but $\gamma$ is not constant on any interval, and $\gamma([0,1])$  is the union of infinitely many loops each containing $[0,0]$.  But for your $\rho$, this can't happen: it's easy to show that there can be at most finitely many $t$ with $\rho(t) = [0,0]$.

Comment: What if we assume that $\gamma$ is an injective application?

Answer (score 1):

Even if $\gamma$ is injective, it's not true. Here's a counterexample:
$$
\gamma(t) =
\begin{cases}
(-e^{1/t},0), & t<0,\\
(0,0), &t=0,\\
\left( e^{-1/t},\ e^{-1/t}\sin \frac{1}{t}\right), & t>0.
\end{cases}
$$
This is $C^1$ (in fact $C^\infty$) and injective, but there's no $C^1$ reparametrization with nonvanishing right-hand derivative at the origin. To see why, note that the slope of the curve at $\gamma(t)$ for $t>0$ is $y'(t)/x'(t)$, which reduces to $\sin\frac 1 t - \cos \frac 1 t$, which has no limit as $t\searrow 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your example. Now it's clear.